# How to avoid creating duplicate channels with the same name?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am programming a support system through the creation of private discord channels and one of the problems that I am facing is that part of the code that I use to avoid creating duplicate channels (that is, with the same name) is not working. Then I leave the specific code that I am talking about (And sorry for my English, I'm Spanish xD)

I have tried placing the exclamation at the beginning of the variable but that does not work and does not create any type of channel even if it does not exist. And if the exclamation is not placed directly that part of the code does not work.

```
if (message.guild.channels.exists("name", "ticket-" + message.author.tag)) return message.channel.send("No");
```

It does not give any error in the console and the only inconvenience that it generates is the failure that if the exclamation is placed at the beginning of the parenthesis of the code it does not allow to create channels (although it does not exist) and if it is not allowed to create unlimited channels with the same first name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code variable from `message.author.tag` to `message.author.id` and it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array of people who currently have a ticket open and check if a user already has one open `array.includes(msg.author.id)` and remove it from the aray once said ticket is closed.